# using a Django ModelForm doesn't want to work well with a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, forms, inline, models

I have a ManyToManyField in a model which uses the 'through' option. Using a Django ModelForm, this seems to be failing giving me a funny error about having to use the model's manager.

I want to be able to edit this inline (i think the admin lets me do this) and looked up it on google, but everything to use this Django Inline Forms is really messy and I want to be able to keep my code clean and understandable.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got my head around inline forms. The documentation is just silly.